# React | Full calendar not rendering all day event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I was trying to block few days in the full calendar, but in UI only a part of it is getting filled
and also I need to prevent click events on those blocked dates.
[Sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/jxt6m)

```
  <FullCalendar
        className={style.calendar}
        defaultView="timeGridDay"
        themeSystem="bootstrap"
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin]}
        header={{
          right: "prev,next today,timeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth",
        }}
        slotLabelInterval="00:30:00"
        slotLabelFormat={{
          hour: "2-digit",
          minute: "2-digit",
          hour12: timezonePref ? false : true,
        }}
        allDaySlot={true}
        weekends={true}
        events={[
          ...events,
          {
            start: "2021-03-06",
            end: "2021-03-06",
            allDay:true,
            display: "background",
          },
        ]}
        ref={this.calendarComponentRef}
        displayEventTime={false}
        nowIndicator={true}
        dateClick={this.onClickDate}
        eventClick={this.onClickEvent}
      />
```

I have tried the below options in the event, still the same result.
{start: "2021-03-06", end: "2021-03-06",display: "background"}
{start: "2021-03-06", allDay:true,display: "background"}[image]

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't match the provided data. Using the event data you showed, they display correctly as background events - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/XWNBQKQ

Comment: @ADyson, my bad corrected the data now. Ignore the events which I have scribbled in the screenshot.
Still getting the same output. The entire day (March 6th) is not getting filled

Comment: I updated with your event data in my demo - https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/XWNBQKQ . It shows correctly as background. I don't think the data is the problem. But it's unclear what is.

Comment: Ah....just noticed you may be using fullCalendar 4 as the base version? This appears to be a bug in fullCalendar 4. If I put your data into vanilla FC 4 I get your result: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/LYbBvwW . I suggest upgrading to a more recent version.

Comment: Oops, Yes that was a version issue fixed, But once upgraded to v5 refs (getAPI()) related actions are completely broken. Is there any solution for this?
@ADyson

Comment: I'm sure there is, yes. Without knowing your specific issues I can't suggest specific fixes. However, please ensure you're doing everything according to the v5 documentation (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5#toc), including the specific documentation for the React plugin (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/react). See also the v4-v5 upgrade guide to help you identify any differences in the API etc: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v4